# Nested Symfony2 Forms: $options['data'] = null in nested form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

As the documentation around this topic is somewhat thin, I got to a dead end.

I have two models: Job and JobAttribute.
A Job has many JobAttributes and a JobAttribute has one Job:

```
class Job {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="JobAttribute", mappedBy="job_attributes")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $attributes;
}

class JobAttribute {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=50)
    * 
    * @var string
    */
    private $type;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job", inversedBy="jobs")
    */
    private $job;
```

Now,I have the following FormClass:

```
class JobType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $f, array $options) {
        $f->add('name', 'text');
        $f->add('attributes', 'collection', array('type' => new JobAttributeType()));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'job';
    }
}

class JobAttributeType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $f, array $options) {
        $attribute = $options['data'];
        $f->add('value', $attribute->getType());
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array('data_class' => 'JWF\WorkflowBundle\Entity\JobAttribute');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'job_attribute';
    }
}
```

Yes, indeed, the type property of JobAttribute contains a Form field type, eg. text.

So, as I call a FormBuilder on JobType in my Controller, $options['data'] is correctly populated with a Job-Object within JobType.
But the nested JobAttributeType's $options['data'] doesn't point to an JobAttribute object. It's NULL.

What's the problem? Where is the association lost? Why is $options['data'] = NULL in nested forms?
Is there a workaround in order to get dynamic field types (out of Doctrine) in a nested form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rely on `$options['data']` when you build the form, as the data can (and will) be changed anytime after building. You should use event listeners instead.

```
$formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    if ($data instanceof JobAttribute) {
        $form->add($formFactory->createNamed('value', $data->getType());
    }
});
```

The documentation for this [can be found in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

Comment: Hi Bernhard. What's about `DataTransformer` that needs form data? In `PRE_SET_DATA` event I can't do anything and if `options['data']` has not a value during building, how can I attach the transformer? Thanks.